# Image bit-plane decomposition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-compression, decomposition

I was wondering how I could extract bit planes of an image for image compression in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

Getting individual bit planes is very easy in MATLAB.   Use the [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html) function.

`bitget` takes in an array / matrix of an integral type (`uint8, uint16`, etc.) and it returns an array / matrix of the same size that gives you the bit at a specified position.

For example, supposing that your image was `A` of size `M x N` and you wanted the least significant bit, you would do this:

```
B = bitget(A, 1);
```

`B` would be a `M x N` matrix where each location gives you the least significant bit for the corresponding pixels in the image.  You would change the second parameter from 1 up to as many bits as the type supported to get the desired bit location you want so from 1, the least significant bit, up to `K`, the most significant bit.

---

If you wanted all bit planes in a single 3D matrix, that can easily be done in the following way assuming an 8-bit unsigned integer grayscale image stored in `A`:

```
B = zeros(size(A, 1), size(A, 2), 8, 'uint8');
for idx = 1 : 8
    B(:,:,idx) = bitget(A, idx);
end
```

This will produce a 3D matrix `B` of 8 slices where the first slice (`B(:,:,1)`) denotes the LSB at each pixel location up to the last slice (`B(:,:,8)`) which denotes the MSB at each pixel location.

Read more about `bitget` on MathWorks' official documentation on the function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html